# Unregistering backbone events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pagination

I'm in a real bottleneck with backbone.
I'm new to it, so sorry if my questios are stupid, as i probably didn't get the point of the system's structure.

Basically, I'm creating ad application which lets you do some things for different "steps". Therefore, I've implemented some kind of pagination system. Each time a page sasisfies certain conditions, the next page link is shown, and the current page is cached.

Each page uses the same "page" object model/view, and the navigation is appended there each time. it's only registered one time anyway, and I undelegate/re-delegate events as the old page fades out and the new one fades in.

If I always use cached versions for previous pages, everything is okay. BUT, if I re-render a page that was already rendered, when I click "go next page", it skips ahead of how many times i re-rendered the page itself.

it's like the "go next page" button has been registered, say, 3 times, and was never removed from the events listener.

It's a very long application in terms of code, and i hope you can understand the basica idea, and give me some hints, without needing to have the full code here.

Thanks in advance, i hope somebody can help me out since i'm in a real bottleneck!

p.s. for some reason, I've noticed that the next/previous buttons respective html is not cached within the page. Weird.

---UPDATE----
I tried the stopListening suggestion, but it didn't work. Here is jmy troublesome button:

```
    // Register the next button
    App.Views.NavNext = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('#nav-next'),

        initialize: function() {
            vent.on('showNext', function() {
                this.$el.fadeIn();
            }, this)
        },

        events: {
            'click': 'checkConditions'
        },

        checkConditions: function() {
            //TODO this is running 2 times too!
            console.log('checking conditions');
            if (current_step == 1)
                this.go_next_step();
            vent.trigger('checkConditions', current_step); // will trigger cart conditions too

        },

        go_next_step: function() {

            if(typeof(mainView.stepView) != 'undefined')
            {
                mainView.stepView.unregisterNavigation();               
            }

            mainView.$el.fadeOut('normal', function(){
                $(this).html('');
                current_step++;
                mainView.renderStep(current_step);
            }); //fadeout and empty, then refill

        }
    });
```

Basically, checkConditions runs 2 times as if the previousle rendered click is still registered. Here is where it's being registered, and then unregistered after the current step fades off (just a part of that view!):

```
        render: function() {
            var step = this;

            //print the title for this step

            this.$el.attr('id', 'step_' + current_step);
            this.$el.html('<h3>'+this.model.get('description')+'</h3>');
            // switch display based on the step number, will load all necessary data

            // this.navPrev = new App.Views.NavPrev();
            // this.navNext = new App.Views.NavNext();


            this.$el.addClass('grid_7 omega');

            // add cart (only if not already there)
            if (!mainView.cart)
            {
                mainView.cart = new App.Models.Cart;
                mainView.cartView = new App.Views.Cart({model: mainView.cart})
                mainView.$el.before(mainView.cartView.render().$el)                                 
            }

            switch (this.model.get('n'))
            {

                case 5: // Product list, fetch and display based on the provious options

                    // _.each(mainView.step_values, function(option){
                    //  console.log(option)
                    // }, this);

                    var products = new App.Collections.Products;
                    products.fetch({data:mainView.step_values, type:'POST'}).complete(function() {
                        if (products.length == 0)
                        {
                            step.$el.append('<p>'+errorMsgs['noprod']+'</p>')

                        }
                        else {
                            step.contentView = new App.Views.Products({collection: products});
                            step.$el.append(step.contentView.render().$el);

                        }
                        step.appendNavigation();

                    });


                break;


            }
            //console.log(this.el)
            return this;
        },

        appendNavigation: function(back) {
            if(current_step != 2)
                this.$el.append(navPrev.$el.show());
            else this.$el.append(navPrev.$el.hide());

            this.$el.append(navNext.$el.hide());
            if(back) navNext.$el.show();

            navPrev.delegateEvents(); // re-assign all events
            navNext.delegateEvents();
        },

        unregisterNavigation: function() {
            navNext.stopListening(); // re-assign all events            
        }
```

And finally, here is the main view's renderStep, called after pressing "next" it will load a cached version if present, but for the trouble page, I'm not creating it

```
renderStep : function(i, previous) { // i will be the current step number
            if(i == 1)
                return this;
            if(this.cached_step[i] && previous) // TODO do not render if going back
            { // we have this step already cached

                this.stepView = this.cached_step[i];
                console.log('ciao'+current_step)

                this.stepView.appendNavigation(true);
                if ( current_step == 3)
                {

                    _.each(this.stepView.contentView.productViews, function(pview){
                        pview.delegateEvents(); //rebind all product clicks
                    })
                }

                this.$el.html(this.stepView.$el).fadeIn();

            } else {

                var step = new App.Models.Step({description: steps[i-1], n: i});
                this.stepView = new App.Views.Step({model: step})
                this.$el.html(this.stepView.render().$el).fadeIn(); // refill the content with a new step
                mainView.cached_step[current_step] = mainView.stepView; // was in go_next_step, TODO check appendnavigation, then re-render go next step

            }


            return this;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `listenTo` and `stopListening` when you are showing or removing a certain view from the screen.

Take a look at docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

All events are binded on initialization of the view and when you are removing the view from the screen then unbind all events.

Read this for detailed analysis: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/